# Detect text-input elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, input

In JavaScript, I would like to detect some key presses. But I want to ignore those keypresses that the user makes while typing into some kind of text input area. How can I achieve that?

I have tried

```
if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    return;
}
if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') {
    return;
}
```

which works in those two elements; but for example, the email-compose element in Inbox by Gmail is a DIV container. Do I want to exclude *all* active DIVs, though? Are there other HTML elements that are used to obtain key input? Is there any much different method that I may have overlooked?

Comment: You should check whether the element is `contentEditable` as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/isContentEditable

Comment: @Teemu: Didn't know there is `isContentEditable` :-o

Comment: @FelixKling `isContentEditable` is very handy when `contentEditable` returns `inherit` from nested elements within a content editable element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd use [jquery](https://www.jquery.com) to normalize your events. From there, try testing [$(event.target).is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

Here is an example that has a div where all events are captured. Events for `<input>` elements are ignored, while others are not, including events for a `<textarea>`:

```js
$('#mydiv').keypress(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is('input')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('not an input box');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <input>
  <span>Spanning area</span>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using jquery? What can it do what the code in my question cannot? Also, my question was about detecting other elements that use text input other that `input` and `textarea`, which your answer does not relate to (the comments above have shown `isContentEditable` to solve that).

Comment: There are (at least) two advantages of using jquery. First, it's much more succinct than traditional JavaScript, and a lot more powerful. Second, and perhaps more important, if you follow the jquery docs faithfully, you don't have to worry (as much) about cross-browser issues. Events still are not consistently implemented across browsers, and jquery does a lot of work to "normalize" events into one standard. To your second question: you could detect elements other than input and textarea just by combining them in an if() statement test. I only captured input events for demo purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still, I feel you have not read my question to the end :) I know how to combine `if`s, I was wondering about which HTML elements to consider to begin with.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know that there is any real way of asking the DOM, "does this element need to receive an event?" Even if you use isContentEditable, a canvas could conceivably receive an event, for example, or a button. Perhaps you should instead only listen for keys being pressed??

Comment: Perhaps there's is not one single way, but there must be A way. Think of how a browser determines whether a backspace key press should be used to a) delete a character in a text input element (of whatever kind that may be) or b) navigate back.